# How to create a tabbed page in .Net Maui?

Tags: c#, android, maui

I have a tabbed page in .Net Maui as follows :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     x:Class="MyApp.Pages.SomeClass"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Resources.Controls"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Pages"
                     Title="Some title">
    <local:Page1 />
    <local:Page2 />
    <local:Page3 />
</TabbedPage>
```

The pages are more or less the same :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     x:Class="MyApp.Pages.Page1"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Resources.Controls"
    xmlns:VerticalStackLayout="clr-namespace:MyApp.Resources.Controls"      
                     Title="Vente">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="Page 1"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

C# code :

```cs
public partial class Page1: ContentPage {
  public Page1() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

The tabbed page works properly on Windows :

[image: Screenshot]

However on physical android device, I'm getting the following exception when opening my tabbed page. None of these pages have a C# stuff. They are 100% empty.

```
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.monodroid_debugger_unhandled_exception C#
0x1A in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12,5 C#
0x23 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:353,26    C#
0xEE in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.TabbedPageManager.SetTabLayout at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Platform\Android\TabbedPageManager.cs:240,5 C#
0x1BD in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.TabbedPageManager.SetElement at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Platform\Android\TabbedPageManager.cs:162,5  C#
0x20 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TabbedPage.CreatePlatformView at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\TabbedPage\TabbedPage.Android.cs:23,4 C#
0x10 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TabbedPage.OnCreatePlatformView at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\TabbedPage\TabbedPage.Android.cs:30,5   C#
0x15 in Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler<Microsoft.Maui.ITabbedView,Android.Views.View>.OnCreatePlatformView at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:72,4 C#
0x1 in Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler.OnCreatePlatformElement at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandler.cs:119,4    C#
0x1 in Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.CreatePlatformElement at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Element\ElementHandler.cs:96,4  C#
0x49 in Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Element\ElementHandler.cs:52,4    C#
0x2 in Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler.SetVirtualView at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandler.cs:125,4 C#
0x2 in Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler<Microsoft.Maui.ITabbedView,Android.Views.View>.SetVirtualView at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:53,4    C#
0x7 in Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler<Microsoft.Maui.ITabbedView,Android.Views.View>.SetVirtualView at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:56,4    C#
0x65 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:64,6 C#
0x2 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:20,11    C#
0x18 in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\VisualElement\VisualElement.Impl.cs:301,5 C#
0xB0 in Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:96,4   C#
0x2 in Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ViewExtensions.ToHandler at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ViewExtensions.cs:44,4  C#
0xAA in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellContentFragment.OnCreateView at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\Shell\Android\ShellContentFragment.cs:145,4 C#
0x24 in AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_ at C:\a\_work\3\s\generated\androidx.fragment.fragment\obj\Release\net6.0-android\generated\src\AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.cs:1999,4 C#
0xD in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:352,5  C#
```

Do .Net Maui tabbed pages work on Android?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong.  That should work on Android too.  I'd look at the bug list for issues with TabbedPage.  Or possibly try deploying to a different device/emulator

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested to use a TabbedPage to navigate through a collection of pages see the maui sample here: [TabbedPage](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/Navigation/TabbedPage)

It works on my Android physical device.

Another option is to use a shell tab bar like in this one sample: [ShellTabBar](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/Navigation/ShellTabBarSample)

Answer (score 2):

I have tested it and if I use TabbedPage, I will have similar errors on the Android simulator. So you may need to use ShellTabBar as much as possible, just like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.SomeClass"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Resources.Controls"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Pages"
             Title="Some title">
    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Title="Cats"                    
                 ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Dogs"                    
                 ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Monkeys"                    
                 ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page3}" />
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```